# How can I disable IE on windows Server 2008 SP2?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-server, dism

I want to disable EOL IE on a windows server 2008 SP2 (non R2), i run the below command :

"dism /online /Disable-Feature /FeatureName:Internet-Explorer-Optional-amd64"

When running the command I get the error message " dism" is not recognized as an internal or external command"

I wonder if dism is available to run it on a windows server 2008 SP2 (non R2) or if there is any other way to disable the IE feature on this server.

Comment: I think you're using the right way just like [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/browsers/installation/disable-internet-explorer-windows#method-4---using-windows-features-with-dism-client-and-server-systems) says. How do you run the command? Do you run the command prompt as administrator?

Comment: @YuZhou yes i run the command as administrator, at an elevated command prompt

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

There might be Dism.exe is missing in your computer. You can follow the steps below to fix the issue:

1. Type `%systemroot%\system32` in Windows search bar. Then click the folder in the search results.
2. Check if the command exists in this folder. For example, here it should be **Dism.exe**.
   [image]
3. If the command exists in `%systemroot%\system32`, you can type **Environment Variables** in Windows search bar and click the search result to open it. Then make sure `%systemroot%\system32` is in **Path**.
   [image]
4. If the command doesn't exist in `%systemroot%\system32`, you can run this command `SFC /SCANNOW` at an elevated command prompt. When the SFC command completes, it may report that “Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violation”. Or that it found and replaced corrupt file. It may also report that it found corrupt files but could not fix the problem.
5. If SFC reports that it did not find integrity violations or that it found but could not fix it, run this command `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth`.
6. After the command finishes running, restart the computer and test again.